# How is the Erlang pdf derived?

Tags: probability

If each arrival is exponentially distributed, then the $k$th arrival time is Erlang distributed. The Erlang PDF is:
$$
f_{Y_k}(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \frac{(\lambda y)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
$$
How is this derived?

Comment: You need each arrival to be _exponentially_ distributed (and independent of past arrivals).  If arrival times are discrete and geometrically distributed with parameter $p$, the $k$-th arrival time is a _negative binomial_ or _Pascal_ random variable with parameters $(k,p)$. Both derivations can be done with a $(k-1)$-fold convolution, via moment-generating functions or characteristic functions, etc.

Comment: Here's a derivation given by convolution: http://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/428s05/queue3.pdf Essentially the Erlang distribution is the result of convolving the exponential distribution with itself k-1 times. Note that convolution as the sum of random variables is particularly important to understanding what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute this by means of a convolution of $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and $Y_k \sim Erlang(k,\lambda)$ resulting in the distribution of $Y_{k+1} = X + Y_k$. (see also [Why is the sum of two random variables a convolution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/331983/164061))

$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
f_{Y_{k+1}}(s) &=&  \int_0^s  \underbrace{ \vphantom{ \frac{(\lambda t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}}  \lambda e^{-\lambda (s-t)}}_{\text{exponential density}} \cdot \underbrace{ \lambda^k e^{-\lambda t} \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}}_{\text{Erlang density with $k$}} dt && \\
& =& \lambda^{k+1} e^{-\lambda s} \int_{0}^s      \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}  dt &=& \underbrace{ \vphantom{ \frac{(\lambda t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}} \lambda^{k+1} e^{-\lambda s} \frac{s^{k}}{k!}}_{\text{Erlang density with $k+1$}} 
\end{array}$$

That a sum of $k$ identical and independent exponential distributed variables is Erlang distributed will follow by induction.

---

Alternatively you can use Fourier transform or the characteristic function to [quickly observe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Basic_manipulations_of_distributions) that characteristic function of the Erlang distribution $\varphi(t)_{\text{Erlang}} = \left(1 - \frac{it}{\lambda} \right)^{-k}$ is a product of the characteristic function of the exponential distribution $\varphi(t)_{exponential} = \left(1 - \frac{it}{\lambda} \right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry for writing in this post, but how would you prove the characteristic function of the Erlang? I have exponential one but I don't know exactly how to do the Erlang one. Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelAnguita I am not sure what you are missing in understanding how to proof/compute the characteristic function.  Anyway, here's the definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition

Comment: I know the definition. But not how to do the specific f.ch of Erlang one.

Comment: @MiguelAnguita $$\phi (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{itx}
 \lambda^k e^{-\lambda x} \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} dx$$ which relates to integrating $\int e^{(it-\lambda) x}x^{k-1} dx $

Comment: Yeah, great, but how would you integrate it in an easy form?

Comment: @MiguelAnguita you can do this with repeated integration by parts (note I should have written limits $0$ to $\infty$ instead of $-\infty$ to $\infty$). You could also do it more in one step and figure out the coefficients of $$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n e^{(it-\lambda)x} x^n$$ such that it's derivative is $$F(x)' = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n ((it-\lambda) e^{(it-\lambda)x} x^n+ n e^{(it-\lambda)x} x^{n-1})$$ which should give you a recursive formula for $a_n$