# How to derive Erlang distribution from the Exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I read that for a random variable $X$ to have Erlang distribution, it will be the sum of identical random variables with exponential distribution, but i cant derive the formula.

The density of an Erland distribution is $f(x;k,\lambda) = {\lambda ^k x^{k-1} e^ {- \lambda x} \over (k-1)!}$.

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: $ f(x;k,\lambda) = {\lambda ^k x^{k-1} e^ {- \lambda x} \over (k-1)!} $

Comment: There are several ways. One is to compute the mgf of the sum as a power of the mgf of the exponentials, separately compute the mgf of the Erlang, and note they are the same.

Comment: This blog post of mine should be helpful: https://justanothermathblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/exponential-distribution/

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250733/how-is-the-erlang-pdf-derived